# Regex for string containing hyphen in the middle but not consecutively

Tags: regex

Can any body suggest me a regex for non consecutive hyphen in the middle of a string?

**Example**

*Should work for:*

- `a`
- `bbb`
- `jsdhj-jsdjk`
- `aaaa-sjjks-askdh-kshskah`

*Should not work for:*

- `-a`
- `ddd-`
- `bbb--bb`
- `hah-hhh--hjh`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: SO probably isn't the appropriate place to post questions asking to solve a regex problem without any context or attempt to solve. Suggest trying to pose a couple of solutions you have tried and what resources you have used.

Comment: Check this web for your test results http://regexr.com/

Comment: or this website: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fS2nH2/1)